# Test if string is valid key prior to memcache.get()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-memcached

Is there a function in Google App Engine to test if a string is valid 'string key' prior to calling `memcache.get(key)` without using `db.get()` or `db.get_by_key_name()` first?

In my case the key is being passed from the user's get request: 
`obj = memcache.get(self.request.get("obj"))`

Somehow I'd like to know if that string is a valid key string without calling the db first, which would defeat the purpose of using memcache.

Comment: What do you mean by a "valid" key? Do you mean "in the right format for a key string", or do you mean "refers to an actual object in the datastore"?

Comment: I mean the right format for a key string to avoid the error `raise datastore_errors.BadKeyError('Invalid string key %s.' % encoded)`.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably the most efficient (and practical) way to determine if the key string is valid.  The code is obviously performing that test for you before it attempts to retrieve the entity from memcache/datastore.  Even better, Google will update that code if necessary.

```
try:
    obj = memcache.get(self.request.get("obj"))
except BadKeyError:
    # give a friendly error message here
```

Also, consider switching to ndb.  Performing a get() on a key automatically uses two levels of cache, local and memcache.  You don't need to write separate code for memcache.

Answer (score 1):

A db module key sent to a client should pass through str(the_key) which gives you an URL safe encoded key. Your templating environment etc.. will do this for you just by rendering the key into a template.

On passing the key back from a client, you should recreate the key with 
`key = db.Key(encoded=self.request.get("obj"))`

At this point it could fail with something like 
`BadKeyError: Invalid string key "thebadkeystring"=.`

If not you have a valid key

`obj = memcache.get(self.request.get("obj"))` won't actually raise BadKeyError because at that point you are just working with a string, and you just get `None` returned or a value.

So at that point all you know is you have a key missing.

However you need to use the memcache.get(self.request.get("obj")) to get the object from memcache, as a `db.Key` instance is not a valid memcache key.

So you will be constructing a key to validate the key string at this point. Of course if the memcache get fails then you can use the just created key to fetch the object with `db.get(key)`

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'm worried about me not being able to control the inbound string, i.e. a user could manipulate it.  I think the re-creation of key will work for these purposes.

Comment: Key manipulation entirely possible. An authorization framework that validates if a particular principal (user, group) has permission to access the entity may be one strategy for addressing this risk.

Answer (score 0):

Any object is a valid key, provided that the object can be serialized using pickle.  If pickle.dumps(key) succeeds, then you shouldn't get a BadKeyError.